# Cakephp form has no data on submit

Tags: php, forms, cakephp

Using cakephp 1.3 I fill out a form, and upon debugging the submit, I notice that

```
data:$("#submit-478065271").closest("form").serialize()
```

is empty. Why would something like that happen? I've checked that the form actually has data, which I can serialize manually. Here is the submit code:

```
echo $this->Js->submit(
        'Sign up',
        array(
            'class' => 'btn btn_submit fr register_submit register_btn_align',
            'url' => array('controller' => 'email_guides', 'action' => 'subscribe'),
            'before' => '$(".error-message").remove();' . $this->Js->get('#loading')->effect(
                'fadeIn',
                array('buffer' => false)
            ),
            'complete' => $this->Js->get('#loading')->effect(
                'fadeOut',
                array('buffer' => false)
            ) . 'debugger;',
            'success' => 'if(data.success) {
                    $("#CustomUserFirstName").val("");
                    $("#CustomUserEmail").val("");
                    $("#EmailGuidesUserStartDate").val("' . date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+1 Weekday')) . '");
                    $("#EmailGuidesUserTerms").attr("checked", false);
                    $("#signupModal").hide();
                } else {

                    $("#signupModal").hide();
                }
            'type' => 'json'
        )
    );
    ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

UPDATE: I've noticed that the form is not a parent of the submit element ... which is very bizarre. This would explain why .closest("form") returns an empty array.